# Why can water be sprayed farther when the pipe outlet is narrowed?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, fluid-statics, bernoulli-equation

Someone told me: This is because the flow rate remains unchanged, so the flow rate of small diameter pipelines is faster.
I don't think this explanation is right: the diameter of the pipe outlet is small, and the flow rate should be reduced. The flow rate is smaller, so the resistance of the pipeline is reduced, and the water is driven by higher pressure, so the flow rate at the outlet of the pipeline is higher. Is my explanation correct?

[image: When the diameter of pipe outlet decreases]

Comment: I don't understand what you're writing very well, but: wouldn't the pressure be constant because the pressure of the fluid depends only on its height, and it's the same in both diagrams?

Comment: Assuming the diagram you've drawn, and using Bernoulli's law, the mass flow rate is $\rho A u=\rho A \sqrt{2gh}$ for h the height difference of the outflow and the height of the water in the tank, $A$ the area of the jet exiting the pipe outlet, and $\rho$ the density of the fluid. So the mass flow rate changes with $A$, but the velocity of the flow is simply a function of $h$. Consequently, if you fixed the mass flow rate, and changed A, then you would change $u$, and as $u\sim A^{-1}$, then narrower orifices mean greater flow speeds.

Comment: This can be easily understood using the continuity equation : https://www.princeton.edu/~asmits/Bicycle_web/continuity.html

Comment: @NickP  the mass flow rate when the outlet is reduced is different from that when the outlet is not reduced.

Comment: @Allure The h of both is constant.

Comment: @himanshu  mass flow is not constant because h is the same.

Comment: @enbinzheng Realizing that my original answer was incorrect I deleted it and posted a new one. Hope it helps.

Comment: @enbinzheng Just out of curiosity, did you run an experiment with the tank?.

Comment: @enbinzheng I am still curious. Did you run an experiment that led you to the question? I did an experiment in which I took a large plastic cup, about 4.5 in tall, 4.5 in. dia at top, 2.5 in. dia at bottom. I drilled a 1/16 in dia hole one inch from the bottom on one side and a 1/4 in dia hole at the same height on the opposite side of the cup. Filled it with water and held it above and over and the middle of the sink. Both streams went the same distance.

Comment: @BobD You must have a hose connected to the outlet of the container, and then pinch the outlet of the pipe. You will find that the flow rate is higher when the pinch is small.

Comment: @enbinzheng I think you mean the velocity is higher (not the flow rate) when the pinch is small, right?

Comment: @BobD Yes, it's the increase of velocity.

Comment: are you talking about steady state, or about the time during and just after pinching the tube?

Comment: @bukwyrm I mean, pinching is faster than not pinching.

Comment: but when? if you have a tube with flowing water, and you constrict the exit, the momentum of the moving water will need to be expended: there will be a spike in pressure and velocity. but a few seconds AFTER the pinching, you will have a steady state: the water will move as if the tube had always been thinner. Which point in time do you mean?

Comment: I am not in the habit of clicking weird links. Could you just put it into words?

Comment: @bukwyrm Workers use hoses to water. They pinch small hose outlets to spray water further. You should have seen this phenomenon.

Comment: This might help : https://youtu.be/TcMgkU3pFBY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing to observe is the lower level in the manometer, that vertical pipe on the left.

The larger opening has higher flow in the pipe, hence more energy loss, hence less pressure at the orifice.

The smaller opening has less flow, less loss, higher pressure.

It’s the pressure right behind/before the orifice that matters.

This effect is *much* more visible with a long garden hose. A wide open outlet is at low pressure as lots of flow loses energy in the hose. Put your thumb over the end, the flow decreases, and you can feel the hose get stiffer as the pressure rises.

Comment: Very well, you've found the final answer to the question. When the outlet of the pipeline is reduced (local, very short section of pipeline), the flow velocity of the non-shrinking pipeline decreases, so the loss decreases, so higher pressure is obtained at the inlet of the narrowing pipeline, so the flow velocity at the outlet of the pipeline increases. Large pressure difference is the reason for the increase of velocity.

Answer (score 2):

This phenomenon is called orifice effect. What happens is the stream discharging from a nuzzle converges to a narrower diameter and faster velocity downstream at a point called [Vena contracta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vena_contracta).

There are empirical methods, based on Bernoulli's law, to calculate the discharge and velocity.

$ q =  c_d A2  \frac {2 (p_1 -  p_2)}{  ρ (1 -  (A_2 / A_1) ^2)^{1/2} }$

$ \text{A1 is the diameter of the pipe, A2 diameter of the nuzzle, A2<A1}$,

$c_d = \frac {A{vena contracta}}{A_2}= discharge \ coeficient $

There are many chrats to find Cd. Usually it ranges around 60% to 80%, [Engineering toolbox](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/orifice-nozzle-venturi-d_590.html)

Comment: My question: The outlet of pinched pipeline and the outlet of non-pinched pipeline have higher velocity. Why?

Comment: @enbin zheng, a rough explanation is $ P*A = 1/2 \dot m*v^2 $ . Because the pressure decreases relatively slowly we can assume for short time interval as constant. And so by narrowing the opening we have to increase the speed to maintain the equilibrium. But air friction to the jet and viscosity of liquid passing through smaller orifice make this relationship nonlinear. The speed of ejection will go up to a certain point then will decrease reducing to droplets. That curve has much to do with the shape of the orifice, its edges, the head of pressure. hence the empirical measures.

Comment: @enbin zheng, and by "pinched pipeline and the outlet of non-pinched pipeline " have higher velocity you mean the velocity of the horizontal pipe with no nuzzle, the answer is the same as above.

Comment: Q=π·r4·Δp/(8ηL) Should the flow rate decrease when the pressure difference remains constant and the diameter decreases?

Answer (score 1):

It is assumed that the pipeline consists of an unshrinking pipeline L1 and a shrinking pipeline L2. L1 is much larger than L2.
[image: pipeline L1 and L2]
As the outlet of the pipeline shrinks and the flow is hindered, the velocity of L1 in the pipeline decreases, so the pressure drop also decreases.
According to the following formula, the pressure drop is proportional to the square of the velocity, so when the velocity decreases, the pressure drop will decrease greatly.

$$h_f=λ \frac{l}{d} \frac{v^2}{2g}$$

Because the pressure drop is greatly reduced, pipeline L2 will get higher pressure, so the flow rate of pipeline L2 will increase.

[Video Interpretation of Sprinkler Speed](https://youtu.be/hZ5fZ3K4_mE)

Answer (score 1):

This question has been bothering me for a while, and here's what I've come up with.

Bernoulli's equation is clearly the starting point to think about this problem: $p + \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 + \rho g h = E$ where $E$ is a quantity they is conserved throughout the fluid, basically its energy per unit volume. In other words, the sum of the kinetic energy, potential energy and pressure is the same everywhere.

With atmospheric pressure roughly equal at the surface of the tank and at the exhaust, all of the potential energy at the surface of the tank should be transformed into kinetic energy at the exhaust such that $v_{\text{exhaust}} = \sqrt{2gh}$.

Note that the diameters of the pipe or of the exhaust aren't in this formula, so under conditions where the Bernoulli equation applies, the narrowing in the nozzle doesn't change anything.

So, since we know this isn't true... what gives?

An effect that's not captured by Bernoulli's equation are friction losses in the pipe: friction in viscous fluids is generally proportional to $v^2$ (see Navier-Stokes equation) and velocity is proportional to the cross-sectional area of the pipe so that doubling the diameter of the pipe while keeping the exhaust diameter  the same would reduce the friction losses by a factor of 16 (not accounting for the change in exhaust velocity, but you get the idea...)

These losses have the form $\alpha l v^2_{\text{pipe}}$ where $\alpha$ is some coefficient which would include things like the viscosity of water and $l$ is the length of the pipe since it makes sense that the losses would scale linearly with that.

Finally, call $\beta$ the ratio of the exhaust diameter to pipe diameter. From this we get $v_{\text{pipe}} = \beta^2 v_{\text{exhaust}}$.

Now equate fluid energy at the exhaust (including losses from the pipe) to energy at the top of the tank (using Bernoulli's equation the $p$ terms since they are almost equal on both ends and dividing by $\rho$). You get:

$\frac{1}{2} v_{\text{exhaust}}^2 + \alpha \beta^4 l v_{\text{exhaust}}^2
= g h$

Solving for $v_{\text{exhaust}}$, we get:
$v_{\text{exhaust}}=\sqrt{\frac{2gh}{1 + 2 \alpha \beta^4 l}}$

Note that taking pipe length $l \rightarrow 0$, or friction coefficient $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ or diameter of the exhaust $\beta \rightarrow 0$ yields the friction-less Bernoulli formula.

(I'm not a physicist so I look forward to replies with corrections/confirmation)

Answer (score 0):

***Why can water be sprayed farther when the pipe outlet is narrowed?***

Your assumption that the water will go further (i.e., velocity will be greater) when the pipe outlet is narrowed is incorrect. For an ideal fluid (assumptions below) the velocity will remain the same and the flow rate will decrease based on the Bernoulli equation and the continuity equation.

See diagram below.

Bernoulli equation (conservation of energy):

$P_{1}+\frac{ρV_{1}^2}{2}+ρgz_{1}= P_{2}+\frac{ρV_{2}^2}{2}+ρgz_{2}$

Continuity (conservation of mass) equation:

$A_{1}V_{1}= A_{2}V_{2}$

Assumptions:

1. Steady flow
2. Incompressible fluid
3. No or negligible viscosity
4. No friction losses
5. The diameter at the top of the tank (assumed circular) is much greater than the diameter of outlet.

Then given

$P_{1}=P_{2}$= 1 atm

$A_{1}>>A_{2}$ therefore, $V_{1}<<V_{2}$

$z_{1}-z_{2}= h$

The velocity at the outlet is

$$V_{2}=\sqrt{2gh}$$

Note that this is identical to the velocity of an object initially at rest that falls to the ground from a height $h$, due to the conversion of potential to kinetic energy. It is independent of the diameter of the pipe outlet. If the velocity is the same and the cross sectional area of the pipe is decreased, then by the continuity equation the flow rate decreases.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: but $P_2 \ne P_1$. $P_2=P_1+ \rho A_1 (z_1 - z_2) g$

Comment: @PaulChilds P1 and P2 are the static pressures OUTSIDE the fluid above the tank and to the left of the outlet, respectively, and are both atmospheric pressure.

Comment: But your Bernoulli equation is not about the air but the fluid.

Comment: You have also said the OP is incorrect when clearly they have experimentally demonstrated it and are now asking why.

Comment: @PaulChilds I read the OP question and saw no statement the question was based on an experiment the OP did. So I assumed it was a theoretical question. For what it's worth, I did conduct an, admittedly crude, experiment. Took a large plastic cup, about 4.5 in tall, 4.5 in. dia at top, 2.5 in. dia at bottom. I drilled a 1/16 in dia hole one inch from the bottom on one side and a 1/4 in dia hole at the same height on the opposite side of the cup. Filled it with water and held it above and over and the middle of the sink. Both streams went the same distance.

Comment: @PaulChilds Regarding $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$, I am applying Bernoulli's at the entrance (at top of tank) and exit (at the outlet) and these are both atmosphere. Since the pressure difference is zero, there is no pressure causing the flow other than the pressure head.

Comment: It's clear from your experiment with a hose that narrowing the hose outlet will increase the speed of the hose outlet. You're studying ideal fluids, and what we're talking about now is actual fluids.

Comment: You have a conceptual error. Formula V2=2gh states that V2 is independent of the size of beaker outlet, not of the pipe outlet.

Comment: @enbinzheng Regarding your first comment, yes the application of the Bernoulli equation is based on an ideal fluid and a coefficient of discharge at the outlet of unity. But my experiment was with a real fluid, water.

Comment: @enbinzheng Regarding your second comment, it doesn't matter if the flow is through a hole on the side of the cup, or a pipe inserted in the hole. I did the experiment again, this time inserting two short pieces of a straw, one about 1/16 dia the other 1/8 dia, both extending about 1/2 from the cup opening, and both being the same length, to represent "pipes" . Repeated the experiment. Same result. I could not perceive any difference in the distance of each stream.

Comment: @enbinzheng Finally, I cut another piece of the small straw and inserted it into the end of the large straw, making a nozzle. I repeated the experiment. Still could not discern any difference in the distance of the streams. I must admit, however, this could be due to the fact that the pressure head is relatively small. At 0.433 psi per foot and a height of 4.5 inc. is only 0.1623 psi head. Compare this to a 40-45 psi pressure of a garden hose.

Comment: @enbinzheng So I don't believe I made any "conceptual error". The only error I might have made is to think the velocity is independent of the opening size for any magnitude pressure head because my experiments did no cover that. I think it would still apply to straight pipes, but obviously not to nozzle with high pressure head where blocking the opening increases velocity even though flow rate is decreased.

Comment: @BobD A simple experiment is that you take a medical tourniquet, insert it into the bottom of the cup, and then compare the pinch outlet with the non-pinch outlet. The result must be: pinch the outlet of the tourniquet, and spray water farther. It should be noted that most of the diameter of the pipeline is unchanged, but only at the outlet. The mistake of your experiment is that you put two different diameter pipes on both sides of the cup.

Answer (score 0):

With a small length pipe, where length is say zero, i.e. it's just a hole in the side of the tank, the speed is bascially identical due to torricelli's law $v=\sqrt{2gh}$ regardless of diameter. This is a frictionless scenario. A thinner hole introduces a negligible amount of friction so the speed will slowly approach zero as the hole becomes microscopic.

As the length of the pipe increases, the speed of the thinner pipe would reduce quicker than the speed of the wider diameter pipe because the effect of friction in a thinner pipe is greater. The speed is actually less for a thinner pipe. The wider diameter pipe connected to the source has a faster velocity water flow.

What you're talking about is a nozzle, and a nozzle only makes an appreciable difference in exit velocity when you have a long set of copper pipes and hose pipe. The nozzle reduces the flow speed in the pipes, meaning less energy is lost to friction along the pipes because friction loss is proportional to velocity squared as well as length, and therefore more energy is available at the nozzle, which is all dynamic pressure energy (which is proportional to velocity squared) because there's always zero pressure potential energy at the end of an open pipe because its at atmospheric pressure and there's no pressure difference between that and atmospheric pressure.

If you put the nozzle directly on the tank, there would be no difference in speed between the nozzle and a pipe of the same length (in fact the speed of fluid coming out of the nozzle would be slightly less because of the friction mentioned in the paragraph before last). This is because the energy available from the hydrostatic pressure is already maximum, but when you have a long hose and pipes, the friction reduces the energy, so the nozzle recovers some of the energy.

Answer (score -1):

The pressure is the same in either case, but as pressure equals force divided by area, you are ejecting less water at higher force in order to maintain the same pressure, hence the droplet spray goes further. Flow rate doesn't (have to) come into it.

Comment: I agree, but maybe throw in an equation for good measure

Comment: Can you write the equation?

Comment: Anything beyond just $F = P A$ is useless when dealing with non-laminar flow. Bernouli only deals with laminar flow.

Comment: What cross-section is your pressure?

Comment: The cross sectional area A is taken wherever you want to measure the force; typically at the point it is ejected from the pipe.

Comment: The manometers show the pressure is different.

Comment: @Bob Really?  where are you measuring the pressure. A manometer is typically a water level and as the water level in the tank is considered the same for the two cases I hardly see how that could be the case.

Comment: @PaulChilds look at the two pictures in the question. Then think about flow loss in the pipe.

Comment: There will be some viscosity loss, but it will not scale to the same degree as the aperture area does in increasing the force.